# Handling a C array passed in an Objective C method

Tags: objective-c

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853698/how-to-pass-an-array-in-by-reference-to-a-function-in-objective-c) and its answers and they clear up some of my confusion, but I'm still concerned about a couple things:

Consider this:

```
int someCArray[5]={1,2,3,4,5};

[self processingTheArray:someCArray];
```

The method is described as:

`-(void)processingTheArray:(int)theCArray;`

Now, the above works, even though I gather it is not the right way to do it. It does provide a compiler warning: `Incompatible pointer to integer conversion.` **Need I be concerned since this is working anyway?**

Using the method in the above linked SO question, I could do this:

`-(void)processingTheArray:(int)theCArray size:(NSUInteger)length;`

However, what do I do with `length` inside `processingTheArray`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`someCArray` is of type `int*`, not `Byte*`. `int` and `Byte` are different sizes, and are incompatible.

By changing your method to `-(void)processingTheArray:(int*)theCArray;`, it will work without warning.

However, the method takes your array in as a *pointer*, and it does not know if `theCArray` includes one int, 5 ints, or 500 ints inside. Unless the array is always the exact same length, you want a `length` parameter to specify the array size, so inside the method, you can loop or do whatever you want.

You could have something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    theCArray[i]; // do something
}
```

inside of your `processingTheArray:` function.

Comment: my apologies, I edited my question while you were writing your answer. I realized that `Byte` had no purpose in my example. Indeed using (int*) works, but so did (int), accessing all indexes was available, just a compiler warning.

Comment: Adding a `*` after `int` should still fix it. I noticed in the question you linked to, the commenter who provided the example with `length` had `- (void)arrayFunction:(Byte)targetArray length:(NSUInteger)length`. I believe this is a typo - the `Byte` should actually be `Byte*`, since you have an array pointer.